# Break out of function that calls eval from within the eval

Tags: php, eval

I want to `eval()` to make the function that calls it to end as well. But I don't want to stop the entire application.

I am using include to include an third party application into my own application. The third party application eventually calls a function that first allows me to inject code via a hook, end then at the end of the function it simply calls `exit();`.

I don't want to edit their code manually. And I also don't want to include the third party application using exec() or readfile() or curl() or include over http or any other similar method. Because I want the client context to stay existing toward the third party script. (Otherwise, the third party script will think that my own server is the client. For example, the third party script will always see that `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`  is `127.0.0.1`. And I don't want that.)

In short, the following is happening:

My application:

```
// do stuff
// ...
chdir("path/to/third/party/application");
include ("path/to/third/party/application/index.php");
chdir("path/to/my/application");
// ...
// do more stuff
```

Third party application:

```
// do some stuff
// ...
doLastStuff();

function doLastStuff() {
    // doing some last stuff
    // ...

    $hook = "..."; // get code from database
    if ($hook) {
        eval($hook);
    }
    exit();
}
```

The problem is that the `exit();` at the end also stops my own script. And I don't want that. Can anyone see a way to stop to avoid that `exit()` stopping my script as well, from inside the hook?

I can put what ever string inside $hook.

Comment: Eval=evil just letting you know:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this myself already. The trick was to raise an Exception inside the eval'd code. And to put the include in a try/catch in my own application.

My Application:

```
// do stuff
// ...
chdir("path/to/third/party/application");
try {
    include ("path/to/third/party/application/index.php");
}
catch (Exception $e) {
}
chdir("path/to/my/application");
// ...
// do more stuff
```

Third party application:

```
// do some stuff
// ...
doLastStuff();

function doLastStuff() {
    // doing some last stuff
    // ...

    $hook = "throw new Exception();"; // get code from database

    if ($hook) {
        eval($hook);
    }
    exit(); // will no longer be executed...
}
```

I could also raise a custom derived Exception class so I only catch my own Exception and leave other Exceptions uncaught.